# Error on setOnClickListerner

Tags: android

I got an error from a simple code that I couldn't figure out.

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, RegisterPage.class));
        }
    });



    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, LoginPage.class));
        }
    });


}
```

}

Error:

> 04-16 22:10:24.290 22576-22576/com.example.cassieleong.drinksmart E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.example.cassieleong.drinksmart, PID: 22576
>                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cassieleong.drinksmart/com.example.cassieleong.drinksmart.RegisterPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)

```
html:

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"

        android:src="@drawable/smalllogo" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:background="#dd900a"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="181dp"
    android:allowUndo="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REGISTER"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:background="#dd900a" />
```

RegisterPage:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/smalllogo" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emergency"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_number"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emergency2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_number2"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button1"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#dd900a"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".HomePage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register_page" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login_page" />
</application>
```

Thank for helping

Comment: Can you post your xml file

Comment: Your layout looks correct to me

Comment: But it giving me the error =/

Comment: The issue appears to be due to a null pointer being passed to one of the onCLicks. I'd suggest determining which by commenting out `startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this, RegisterPage.class));`  and then uncommenting that if the error persists (if not then the null pointer is in that piece of code) and commenting out the other startActivity code. Either 'HomePage.this', 'RegisterPage.class' or 'Login.Page.class' resolves to 'NULL'.

Comment: Can you post RegisterPage

Comment: post your manifest xml please

Comment: See above edited post

Comment: You're calling `setOnClickListener()` on a null `Button` reference in `RegisterPage`'s `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Post your register class

Comment: @Mike M. Can I borrow your glasses. I didn't see registerpage in the error message until you posted. :)

Comment: You are calling some random buttons from another layout! I guess you have bigger problems than this :)) I recommend take a look at your whole design and what you expect from each element

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that outer `LinearLayout` is ended before the buttons are defined.

Does it work when you move the `</LinearLayout>` tag to the bottom?

```html
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/smalllogo" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LOGIN"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:background="#dd900a"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="181dp"
    android:allowUndo="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REGISTER"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:background="#dd900a" />
</LinearLayout>
```